# How to Plot top-2 rows vs others in R ggplot (pie chart)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say, I have a dataset where I count the number of occurrences of the letter `a` to `z`.
I want to plot a pie chart in R, which shows top-2 counts vs the other. I have the following code which generates the dataset and counts the number of occurrences of the letter a through z.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters,100,rep=TRUE))
dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = length(ID))
```

It's output looks like this:

```
   ID no_rows
1   a       2
2   b       3
3   c       3
4   d       3
5   e       2
6   f       4
7   g       6
8   h       1
9   i       6
10  j       5
11  k       6
12  l       4
13  m       7
14  n       2
15  o       2
16  p       2
17  q       5
18  r       4
19  s       5
20  t       3
21  u       8
22  v       4
23  w       5
24  x       4
25  y       3
26  z       1
```

Top-2 results are rows 13 `(no_rows=7)` and 21`(no_rows=8)`. So my pie chart should have Top-2 `(7+8=15)` and others (sum of remaining `no_rows`).

I am new to R and plotting.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: No clue. I've been thinking of sorting and counting. But I believe R has better constructs to do this.

Comment: Figuring out how to count the ROWS in R took me a while.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like the following. The gist is to `ungroup` so the data sorts, then `arrange` to sort the way you want. Then I used a `case_when` along with `row_number` to give labels to the data. Then `ggplot` the pie. Although I'm no fan of pie charts :)

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
dat <-  data.frame(ID = sample(letters,100,rep=TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = length(ID)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(desc(no_rows) ) %>%
  mutate( label = case_when(row_number() <=  2 ~ ID, 
                            row_number() > 2 ~ 'all other')) ->
  data_to_plot

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data_to_plot, aes(x=factor(1), fill=label))+
  geom_bar(width = 1)+
  coord_polar("y")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-14 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).